# return a default timestamp object instead of null

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a Timestamp object-

```
java.sql.Timestamp time = null;
```

and I have a `datetime` value `val_time` in a DB table.

```
val_time datetime
```

The situation is, while performaing an operation, this `val_time` is not getting updated (which is pretty normal in my case). While reading from DB, naturally the datetime value will be null. So the timestamp object will also be null. **My question is -** can we get some default value other than null?

Comment: if possibly you wanted to change datetime to timestamp, there is a simple (and robust) solution is to `val_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. The other option is to use trigger to insert default values as `NOW()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since you stated in the tags you use mysql, I would recommend you using IFNULL statement in your query to get a default value instead of NULL then.

```
SELECT IFNULL(colname, your-default-value) FROM xyz;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull